# In python, what's the difference between math.sin(x) and sin(x)?

Tags: python

Which one is better:

```
import math
math.sin(x)
```

or

```
from math import *
sin(x)
```

And what's the difference?

Comment: Is the difference not obvious? And the first is better; it's more explicit; see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: It's just a matter or readability, which BTW is important to Python programmers. `from math import sin` would be the preferred over `from math import *` since it allows to trace back an import in the code.

Comment: It is not the only reason, `from something import *` might override previously defined variables/functions/whatever, and it makes it hard to debug

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using a wildcard `from module import *`, since you dont know what exactly you have imported into your current namespace. This can lead to confusion if there are conflicts in the names of such items.

You should use `from math import sin` since it would make it very clear that you only require `sin`.

Using (`import math` and using `math.sin`) or `from math import sin` is more of a personal choice unless there is another variable or function having same name in the namespace. If such a case is happening, then using `math.sin` is the better way

Answer (score -1):

It's mostly about reading it nicer, so that you know where sin came from.

However there is the danger of importing modules with clashing names. If another module has something named 'sin' that you also import with the * wildcard, then you actually will only have one of them.

Using math.sin is extra explicit to avoid those cases. And when you write larger programs where you've imported whole modules indiscriminately, it's easier to miss that you have clashing names.